# как найти в контейнере set типа string состоящую из 9ти элементов, наибольшую строку и вывести ее?

Tags: c++, строки, set

не могли бы вы подсказать как найти в контейнере set  типа string состоящую из 9ти элементов, наибольшую строку и вывести ее?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зависит от того, какой компаратор использует `set` - вдруг строки упорядочены, скажем, по длине, а не с помощью лексикографического сравнения?

Если все же с его лексикографической помощью, и в вашем условии наибольшая строка тоже имеется в виду "лексикографически наибольшая" - то для множества `s` просто за O(1)

```
*prev(s.end())
```

В общем случае, если компараторы различны - за O(N)

```
*max_element(s.begin(),s.end())
```

или с указанием третьим аргументом своего компаратора...

И не расстраивайте с самого утра, утверждая, что вы не знаете, как выводятся строки...

Comment: только это будет не O(1) а, если не ошибаюсь, логорифмическая сложность, так как это бинарное дерево

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Это если *искать*, а искать последний элемент не нужно - он известен, поиска никакого нет...

Comment: ну это зависит от реализации дерева - мне, к сожалению, не известно записано ли в стандарте хранение последнего элемента, но когда я реализовывал свое дерево (авл), то у меня хранился лишь корень - первый и последний элементы находились банальным поиском самой левой и правой ноды соответственно.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Здесь не самописная, а очень конкретная реализация, которая должна соответствовать требованиям стандарта...

Comment: я не спорю, что реализация `set` должна соответствовать стандарту - это очевидно, НО, а в стандарте разве прописано, что помимо корня бинарное дерево должно хранить указатели на первый и последний элементы? Кастомную реализацию я привел в качестве примера того, что если в стандарте четко не оговорен этот пункт, то реализация может быть какая угодно: может хранить указатели на первый и последний элементы (читай самый левый и самый правый), а может как моя - не хранить их, а обращаться к ним согласно свойствам дерева (опять таки: самый левый и самый правый элементы)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Итак, вы всерьез считаете, что `end()` - это O(N)? :) `set::end()` - [O(1)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/end), `prev(n)` - [линейная сложность от n](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev), так что для фиксированного значения `prev(1)` - O(1). В стандарте, кстати, не уверен, что вообще прописано, что `set` - это именно бинарное дерево. Но тут утверждать не буду...

Comment: `Итак, вы всерьез считаете, что end() - это O(N)?` - ну вы вообще читали то что я написал? Я же писал, что это зависит того, хранятся ли указатели на самый левый и самый правый элементы - если хранятся, то это O(1), но если не хранится, а используется, как раз таки, свойство бинарного дерева для взятия первого и последнего элементов, то, несомненно - это ЛОГАРИФМИЧЕСКАЯ сложность (а не `O(N)` - это линейная). К тому же в ссылке что вы привели ничего о сложности не говорится

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Это ни от чего не зависит! В стандарте написано, что `end()` - константная сложность. И именно по той ссылке, что я привел. Если вы в состоянии прочесть **Complexity** *Constant* как O(lg N)... Вобщем, я написал в ответе, как оно должно быть по стандарту, а не как ваша придуманная, противоречащая стандарту реализация делает. Со своей стороны эту пустую дискуссию закрываю.

Comment: ну а если вы в состоянии читать и думать, то можете увидеть что речь идет о последнем элементе, а не итераторе на конец, который указывает на элемент следующий за последним. И, опять таки, если вы представляете себе структуру бинарного дерева, то `prev` - имеет не константную сложность (надеюсь не нужно объяснять почему). Так что сложность `std::prev(std::end())` != сложности одной только функции `std::end`

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Считайте, что вы попали на дурака и невежу. Позвольте в ответ и мне считать так же.

Comment: мдаа... а я был о вас лучшего мнения, даже несмотря на ваше лицемерие (надеюсь вы не забыли о том эпизоде). Вы видимо забыли для чего предназначен этот форум и простую аксиому, что в спорах рождается истинна. Я лишь заметил, что сложность данной операции зависит от реализации контейнера и, если вас это задевает, то уж извините, но это много говорит о вас и не в ваше пользу

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, @Harry, `end()` - константное время [пруф](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements.general#4). `prev(it, n)` - эквивалентен `advance(it, -n)` [пруф](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.operations#7). Который для bidirectional iterators (Именно такой итератор использует `set` [пруф](http://eel.is/c++draft/associative.reqmts#6)) просто использует инкремент/декремент `n` раз [пруф](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.operations#1).

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, @Harry, В случае `prev(s.end())` используется декремент один раз. Операция декремента итератора выполняется за константное **амортизированное** время [пруф](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements.general#13). Таким образом, нельзя утверждать, что сложность одного единственного декремента, используемого в `prev(s.end())`,не зависит от размера контейнера.

Comment: [iterator++ complexity for stl map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22013987/iterator-complexity-for-stl-map)